# Showing that $T\in End(\mathbb{R}^3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Consider the map:
$$T:(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto(2x_1-x_2,x_2+x_3,4x_3)\qquad\mathbb{R}^3\mapsto\mathbb{R}^3$$
I want to show that $T\in End(\mathbb{R})$, which, if I'm not mistaken, means that I must show that it is well-defined and linear. I know how to show that it is linear, but I do not know how to show that it is also well-defined. I need to show that there exists only one element in the codomain for each element in the domain, but how can I do that?

Comment: I don't see any problem. Given $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ there's no ambiguity in computing $T(x)$.

Comment: Note: it doesn't make sense to check that $T$ is linear before you check that $T$ is well-defined! Linearity is a property of functions, and "checking that $T$ is well-defined" really means "checking that $T$ is a function", so it doesn't even make sense to ask if $T$ is linear or not before you've checked well definedness.

Comment: Given the presentation, it's obvious that $T$ is well-defined.  That (being well defined) tends to be an issue you have to worry about when your objects are defined in terms of representatives of equivalence classes.  For example, there's actually work to do to show that the obvious definition of, say, modular addition is well defined.  It's not immediate (though it's pretty easy to see) that $3+6 \equiv 8+6 \pmod{5}$, but that needs to be true because $3 \pmod{5}$ and $8 \pmod{5}$ are the same object.

Comment: I'm just not sure the professor will accept that 'it is obvious'. I'm wondering what to answer if a similar question pops up at the exam.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk, I did not mean to say that I wanted to check linearity first. What I wanted to say is that the problem is how to show that it is well-defined, since I already know how to show that a map is linear.

Comment: There's not much more to say than, "Two different elements of $\Bbb R^3$ will always have *distinct* representations of the form $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$.  Putting it another way, if the ordered triples are different, then they define different elements.  Once you know that, you know that $T$ is well defined.

Comment: Okay, thank you @RobertShore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not really about linear algebra at all, I think, but rather the notations we use when defining functions in general.

First of all, you have a slight typo in your post: the definition of $T$ should read

$$T : (x_1, x_2, x_3) \mapsto (2x_1 - x_2, x_2 + x_3, 4x_3) \quad \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$$
or (even better in my opinion)
$$T = (x_1, x_2, x_3) \mapsto (2x_1 - x_2, x_2 + x_3, 4x_3) : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$$
Either of these two options would be fine, but the way you wrote it (with $\mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$) is definitely not correct (w.r.t. any convention I've seen).

The symbol $\mapsto$ (read as "maps to") is used to describe what a function actually does – more precisely, $[\text{something}] \mapsto [\text{other thing}]$ means "the function which, when given the input $[\text{something}]$, returns $[\text{other thing}]$". On the other hand, the symbol $\to$ (read as "to") is used to described the domain and codomain of a function – $f : A \to B$ means "$f$ is a function whose domain is $A$ and whose codomain is $B$". These two arrows convey very different kinds of information, so it's important to use the right symbols in the right places, at least if you want to convince others you know what's going on.

With that out of the way, let's talk about the actual definition of $T$ here. As previously mentioned, $(x_1, x_2, x_3) \mapsto (2x_1 - x_2, x_2 + x_3, 4x_3)$ is telling you that $T$ is meant to be the unique function such that $T(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (2x_1 - x_2, x_2 + x_3, 4x_3)$. Such a function clearly exists (formally, it is the set of ordered pairs $$\{((x_1, x_2, x_3), (2x_1 - x_2, x_2 + x_3, 4x_3)) : (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3\}$$), and this is all that's meant by $T$ being "well-defined". The reason we sometimes actually need to check well-definedness is that occasionally the inputs to the purported function (when written as $[\text{input}] \mapsto [\text{output}]$) aren't precisely the elements of the domain, or sometimes the outputs aren't clearly elements of the codomain. In your case, these were non-issues: the input was precisely the form of an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the output was clearly an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

As others have mentioned in the comments, though, these concerns can often be serious. For example, when trying to define functions from sets of equivalence classes (e.g. defining addition in modular arithmetic), it's important to check that the output of the function doesn't depend on the way you chose to *represent* the input – that is, while an arbitrary equivalence class may be represented by $[a]$, this representation is not unique unless each equivalence class has exactly $1$ element. As such, a function whose definition looks like $[a] \mapsto 2a$ might fail to be well-defined, because $[a]$ and $[a']$ might be exactly the same without $2a$ and $2a'$ being the same (then we'd have one element of the domain which is being sent to two different elements of the codomain, violating the definition of "function").

Another different example would be (for example) the function

$$n = z \mapsto z \overline{z} : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$$

Here, the input to the function is just an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{C}$, so there's no issue there. However, the output of the function, $z \overline{z}$, is not *obviously* a real number, so to check that $n$ is well-defined, you would need to prove that $z \overline{z}$ is a real number for each complex number $z$ (indeed this is true, as I'm sure you're well aware ).

Comment: Thank you for a very clear explanation.